# rbind dataframes as an output from built function

Tags: function, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame like this :

```
set.seed(10040)
my_data <- data.frame(X.1 = c(188.1,188.2,188.3),
                      ID_1A = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      ID_1B = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      ID_1C = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      X.2 = c(188.1,188.2,188.3),
                      ID_2A = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      ID_2B = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      ID_2C = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      X.3 = c(188.1,188.2,188.3),
                      ID_3A = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      ID_3B = runif(3, 13, 15),
                      ID_3C = runif(3, 13, 15))
```

With much more rows and columns. Using the functions `gather` and `rbind`, I would like to build a function that automatically re-shapes the dataframe in order to get all the informations in each raw. In the end, every 4 columns I need to use `gather` to re-shape the data, and then bind all rows from these 'sub-dataframes'.

So far I have this :

```
my_function <- function(data, col_min, col_max){

  output <- data[,c(col_min:col_max)]  %>%
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    gather(treatment,intensite,substring(colnames(df[col_min+1]), 1, 7):substring(colnames(df[col_max]), 1, 7)) %>%
    `colnames<-`(c('X','ID','value'))

  return(rbind(output))

}
```

I can run the function without issue for the first 'sub-dataframe':

```
clean <- my_function(data = my_data, col_min = 1, col_max = 4)
```

But I can't find a way to add the other sub-dataframes.

I tried to run these :

```
clean <- my_function(data = my_data,
           col_min = seq(from = 1, to = 49, by = 4),
           col_max = seq(from = 5, to = 52, by = 4))
```

and

```
for(i in seq(from = 1, to = 49, by = 4)){

  output = my_funtion(data = my_data,
                     col_min = i,
                     col_max = i+3)
  clean = rbind(output)

}
```

But I get error messages because `rbind` doesn't like the multiple values for `col_min` and `col_max`.

There is something I'm missing here, and I'm assuming the answer is in the `apply` family for making `rbind` work, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague helped me to solve my problems : I could either use the `lapply` function or build a for loop as follow :

Option 1 :

```
    fun_import <- function(data){

      cols <- ncol(data)
      tables <- lapply(seq(1, cols-3, 4), function(i){
        data[, i:(i+3)]  %>% 
          gather(treatment, intensite,substring(colnames(data[i+1]), 1, 7):substring(colnames(data[i+3]), 1, 7)) %>% 
          `colnames<-`(c('X','ID','value'))
      })

      return(do.call(rbind, tables))
    }
```

Then run :

```
output <- fun_import(my_data)
```

Option 2 :

```
fun_import <- function(data){

  cols <- ncol(data)
  seq_col <- seq(1, cols-3, 4)
  n <- length(seq_col)
  df <- vector("list", n)
  j = 1

  for (i in seq_col){

    df[[j]] <- data[, i:(i+3)]  %>% 
      gather(treatment, intensite,substring(colnames(data[i+1]), 1, 7):substring(colnames(data[i+3]), 1, 7)) %>% 
      `colnames<-`(c('X','ID','value'))
    j = j + 1
  }

return(do.call(rbind, df))
}
```

Then run :

```
output <- fun_import(my_data)
```